# Populate email input on HTML form from email value within google sheets cell

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've created a pop-up email dialog box within google's html editor as follows with the input for email as follows:

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="mail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="">
```

In my .gs file I'm storing the value of my cell containing the email address I want to use as follows:

```
function getEmail()
 {
   var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Template");
   var row=15;
   var column=3;
   var contactAddress=Utilities.formatString('%s',s.getRange(row, column).getValue());
   Logger.log(contactAddress);
 }
```

This works fine and is capturing the email address correctly and logging it. I now need to change the 'value' of my email input so that it populates with this address when the diolog opens. So I have the following in my HTML file:

```
window.onload = function (contactAddress)
{
   document.getElementById('mail').value=contactAddress;
}
```

However, this is resulting in '[object Event]' being populated. I feel I'm close here but can't quite get it over the line!!!!

UPDATE:

So I added this to my .gs:

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('emailTemplate')
  .setWidth(800)
  .setHeight(500);
  html.myvar = new getEmail();
  html.evaluate().getContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showModalDialog(html, ' ');
 }
```

However, when I run the script I get an error stating Object does not allow properties to be added or changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Original answer deleted.

So here is my answer to your problem. Tested it out, and it works.

My HTML page is set up like this just to test it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function onSuccess(contact) {
     //var contactAddress = google.script.run.getEmail();
        document.getElementById('mail').value=contact;
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getEmail();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="mail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="">

  </body>
</html>
```

My .gs file contains

```
function getEmail()
 {
   var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var row=1;
   var column=3;
   var contactAddress=Utilities.formatString('%s',s.getRange(row, column).getValue());
   Logger.log(contactAddress);
   return contactAddress;
 }
```

The only real difference is that I added a return statement (and changed the row from 15 to 1 for my test).

Seems the main problem was how you were calling the function on the HTML page. It needed a `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()` call instead of a `window.onload = function()` call.

Comment: Thanks for this - I added an update on the bottom of my post as I am getting an error :(

Comment: try evaluating the email function before evaluating the template first. So var email = getEmail(); html.myvar = email;. The new myFunction() may have been part of a project in progress.

Comment: In order to evaluate the variable, you have to call HTMLService.createTemplateFromFile() not createOupt

Comment: hey @DaveB1, I updated my answer and tested the output successfully.This should solve your problem if you haven't already.

Comment: sorry was trying to accept your response last week but wasn't working!!! Now seems to have done so :) Cheers for your help - I'm now deep-diving into a more thorough JavaScript course ;)

Comment: @Daveb1 no problem. I didn't come up with the working and tested solution until last night. Thanks for selecting the answer! Good luck on the JS. What helped me with GAS was just obsessively reading the guides on the dev page.

Comment: yeah that's what I will do. But I think before delve too much further into GAS, I need to properly master JS :) Cheers for all your help - much appreciated!